# 'Sitecore.DataExchange.Tools.DynamicsConnect.Models.DynamicsConnectCollectionModel, 1.0' does not have a remote version

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

I have installed `Data Exchange Framework 7.0.0` and `Sitecore Connect™ for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 7.0.0` in Sitecore 10.2. In this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/Connect for Dynamics Tenant Branch/Endpoints/Providers/xConnect/xConnect Client Endpoint`, I have added `Collection Service Connection String Name` (xconnect.collection) and `Collection Service Certificate Connection String Name` (xconnect.collection.certificate).

[image]

but when I am getting the error `Run Troubleshoot` I am getting below error:

[image]

Below error is coming on the log file:

```
14448 13:01:41 ERROR [Data Exchange]    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.Client.BaseXConnectServiceClientConverter`1.CreateNewClientConfiguration(XConnectClientSettings settings)
   at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.Client.BaseXConnectServiceClientConverter`1.Convert(XConnectClientSettings settings)
   at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.DefaultXConnectClientHelperFactory.ToXConnectClient(XConnectClientSettings clientSettings)
   at Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.XConnect.Troubleshooters.TestXConnectClientEndpointConnection.Troubleshoot(Endpoint endpoint, TroubleshooterContext context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved after the below steps:

- Go to this location `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/Connect for Dynamics Tenant Branch/Endpoints/Providers/xConnect/xConnect Client Endpoint`
- Go to the `Collection Model` Path which is `/sitecore/system/Settings/Data Exchange/Providers/xConnect/Collection Models/Connect for Dynamics/Connect for Dynamics Collection Model`
- Click on `Convert Model to JSON`, and it will download the JSON file.
  -[image: List item]

- Deploy this JSON file to below two locations:

  ```
  <xConnectWebsite>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\Models

  <xConnectWebsite>\App_Data\Models
  ```